# Recursion in JavaScript With IF and WHILE

Tags: javascript, recursion

I just come up with little strange behavior in Javascript Recursion. My code

```
var temp1 = function(maxLength,accNumber) {

    if(accNumber.length < maxLength)
    {
        accNumber = '0'+accNumber; 
        temp1(maxLength,accNumber);
    }
    return accNumber;
};
console.log(temp1(5,"23"));
```

**So Here I am expecting output as "00023" but its giving "023" which is not expected.**

**But same code with while loop I am getting expected output. I am not understanding why.**

```
var temp1 = function(maxLength,accNumber) {

    while(accNumber.length < maxLength)
    {
        accNumber = '0'+accNumber; 
        temp1(maxLength,accNumber);
    }
    return accNumber;
};
console.log(temp1(5,"23"));
```

Which give me output "00023" as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you are missing a `return` statement inside your `if` block:

```js
var temp1 = function(maxLength,accNumber) {

    if(accNumber.length < maxLength)
    {
        accNumber = '0'+accNumber; 
        return temp1(maxLength,accNumber);
    }
    return accNumber;
};
console.log(temp1(5,"23"));
```

So the code wasn't returning anything if the `if` condition was passed, that explains why you got `023` instead of `00023`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your recursive call from

`temp1(maxLength,accNumber);`

to

`return temp1(maxLength,accNumber);`

Without the new `return` above, your code is detecting that `accNumber.length` is less than `maxLength` and correctly adding a `'0'` to the front. However, your recursive call is not modifying the local variable `accNumber`, and not returning, so it is basically doing nothing. After the recursive call, the program will exit the `if` block, and return the original `accNumber`, which is `023`.

Comment: @AgataB My edit had nothing to do with the logic of my answer, just added a description of why my answer works.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qa6chtzt/ in this jsFiddle I get Maximum call stack size exceeded. Unless I misunderstood what you're changing.

Comment: `return accNumber` stays the same, `temp1(maxLength,accNumber);` is the one that is changed.

Answer (score 1):

In the if loop, it's detecting that the length is smaller than `maxLength`, so it adds the 0 at the start and is done with the loop. It doesn't check again, if the length is still smaller. So after adding a single 0, it is done with the loop and returns output.

On the other hand the while loop will keep checking after each iteration.

Your function with if should look something like this:

```
function(maxLength,accNumber) {

    if(accNumber.length < maxLength)
    {
        accNumber = '0'+accNumber;
        return temp1(maxLength,accNumber);
    }
        return accNumber;

};
```

Comment: The code continues to execute until the if statement fails, but the value of the variables while returning back up to the first iteration of the recursion are lost (except the first value, which just gets returned). See my answer (which references answers other people have given for this as well).

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be a duplicate of [Strange result using recursion with while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423420/strange-result-using-recursion-with-while-loop), but I wanted to play with this to see if type coercion might be involved.

I have re-authored this here, uncomment the console.logs to see more detail: [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdeanindy/6o1x2rc7/).

This is a scope issue from what I can tell, the if is creating a new scope each time and upon finally exiting, returns the first recursive value for accNumber (023) rather than the innermost recursive scope value (00023). The difference is that the while loop doesn't lose scope in the same way the if version of this does.

```
var temp1 = function(maxLength,accNumber) {

    if(accNumber.length < maxLength) // There is no iteration
    {
        accNumber = '0' + accNumber;
        temp1(maxLength,accNumber); // This creates a new scope
    }
    return accNumber; // You're only returning the initial iteration result
};
console.log(temp1(5,"23"));
```

But in the while version...

```
var temp1 = function(maxLength,accNumber) {

    while(accNumber.length < maxLength)
    {
        accNumber = '0'+accNumber; 
        temp1(maxLength,accNumber); // Since it is in a while, scope is maintained
    }
    return accNumber;
};
console.log(temp1(5,"23"));
```